# How can I make R maintain utf8 encodings?

Tags: r, utf-8, rstudio, ascii

I have utf8 encoded text that R seems to be representing as ascii. Here is the simplest case in the R console. Is there a way to force R to encode the characters in utf8?

[image: Running in R console]

Comment: Your data is UTF-8, but Rstudio is _printing_ it using ASCII

Comment: How do I force it to print using utf-8?  For example, I'm using GT to render this data as tables, I it prints all these angle brackets.

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this an R notebook because that doesn't look like the R console. If so, what attributes do you have in the header? What does `sapply(data, Encoding)` return?

Comment: It is an R notebook on Windows. sapply returns "UTF-8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use knitr or DT libraries to output your table ? It worked for me.

E.g. :

```
tribble(
  ~x,  ~y, ~ z,
  "a", 1:3, "校",
  "♫", 4:6, 5
) %>% 
  knitr::kable()

tribble(
  ~x,  ~y, ~ z,
  "a", 1:3, "校",
  "♫", 4:6, 5
) %>% 
  DT::datatable()
```

Comment: Those work for me too. Apparently R understands the text to be UTF-8, it just doesn't display it that way.